# YAML/yamljs string deserialization behaviour

Tags: javascript, yaml

I was testing YAML (yamljs) with random inputs (please don't ask why it's a long story :D). I'm not very well versed in the YAML spec, but as far as I understand YAML should be able to serialize and deserialize primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) without an object or array wrapper. This however doesn't always seem to be the case.

I isolated one failing case:

```
import YAML from 'yamljs'

describe('YAML', () => {
  it('should be equal to the input', () => {
    const str = '0xn5t'
    expect(YAML.parse(YAML.stringify(str))).toBe(str)
  })
})
```

Where it `'0xn5t'` is somehow parsed back to `5`

```
Expected: "0xn5t"
Received: 5
```

Could someone please guide me to the spec where this behaviour is explained? Could this be an issue with the library I'm using?

Comment: I don't know yamljs, but I know [eemeli/yaml](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml) and can highly recommend to try it out. It gets this right, and it uses the official [YAML Test Suite](https://github.com/yaml/yaml-test-suite)

Comment: @tinita thank you, I'm gonna check out if the behaviour matches yamljs's!